# Possibility of preserving Lipschitz continuity

Tags: functional-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let $f : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a locally Lipschitz continuous function and $f(0)=0$. I want to show that if $u \in C([0,T];L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{N}))$, then $f(u(\,\cdot\,))$ is locally Lipschitz in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$. Is there any natural assumption in which the argument can work? I know that replacing $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ with $C_{0}(\Omega)$ for $\Omega$ a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ works well.

Any help is much appreciated here! Thank you very much!

Comment: What does the notation $u\in C([0,T];L^2 (\mathbb{R}^N ))$ mean?

Comment: @AngelaRichardson It means that $u$ is a continuous function from $[0,T]$ to $L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$, where $L^2$ is given the norm topology. The space of such functions is a Banach space.

Comment: The domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$ but the range of $u$ is $L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$. Rather than $f(u)$, do you mean $f^*(u)$, where $f^*:L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)\rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$ satisfies $f^*(u(x))(y)=f(u(x)(y))$ for all $x\in[0,T]$, $y\in \mathbb{R}^N$?

Comment: we can define $f(u(t,x))$ pointwise in $[0,T]\times\mathbb{R}^{N}$ since $u$ itself is a mapping from $(t,x)\mapsto u(t,x)\in\mathbb{R}$. But I want to preserve the good Lipschitz continuity of the original $f$ in $f(u(t))$ as an $L^{2}$ function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even in the simple case of $f(x) = x^2$, $u\mapsto f(u)$ is not locally Lipschitz in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$: for
$$
\|f(u+v) - f(u)\|_{L^2} = \|(u+v)(u-v)\|_{L^2}.
$$
By taking $v=0$, we see that for $f$ to be locally Lipschitz, you need that for all $R>0$, there is a constant $C_R$ so that for $u\in B(0,R) \subset L^2$, you have
$$
\|u^2\|_{L^2} \leq C_R\|u\|_{L^2}.
$$
However, the change of variable $u_\lambda(x) = \lambda^{N/2}u(\lambda x)$ preserves the $L^2$-norm.
Putting $u_\lambda$ into the above inequality, we find that
$$
\lambda^{N/2}\|u^2\|_{L^2} = \|u_\lambda^2\|_{L^2} \leq C_R\|u_\lambda\|_{L^2} = C_R\|u\|_{L^2}
$$
and taking $\lambda\to\infty$ we see that no such $C_R$ can exist.
By a similar argument no function of the form $f(x) = |x|^r$, $r>1$ can give you such a Lipschitz bound.

Typically, to conclude this sort of bound one needs much more information. You need to know the structure of $f$, the function space you are working on, and what specific estimates (e.g. Sobolev embedding and the like) are available in your function spaces.

Answer (score 1):

This does not work without any further assumptions on $f$. There is no guarantee that $t\mapsto f(u(t))$ is in $L^2$ for some $t$. For instance, take $v\in L^2\setminus L^4$. Set $u(t):=v$, $f(u):=u^2$, then $f(u(t))\not\in L^2$ for all $t$.

Also local Lipschitz continuity of $f$ does not go well with $L^2$-functions. Such functions are potentially unbounded, so $f$ is potentially applied to values from an unbounded set.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer! I am in the position to prove some local existence of some nonlinear heat PDE but maybe I need to find another way.